# Structuring the class and the methods,Java

Tags: java, oop, methods

I asked this question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171006/structuring-the-class-and-the-methods-java?noredirect=1#comment323993_171006), but someone put it on hold saying that it is more appropriate to ask it here, So the question is

Suppose that I am having an application and that application is having a class which generates a random String for me from a method and then I create a secret from that string.

The code is something like the following,

```
public class MyRandomStringGeneratorClass
{
    private String generatedRandomString;
    public String generateRandomString()
    {
        //some logic
        this.generatedRandomString = someRandomStringGenerator();
    }
    public String generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString()
    {
        //some encryption of the String 'generatedRandomString'
    }

}



public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyRandomStringGeneratorClass obj = new MyRandomStringGeneratorClass();
        String randomString = obj.generateRandomString();
        String secretFromRandomString = obj.generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString();
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is what if the user of the API have not generated the random String and called the secret generator method upfront. This will give him/her a nullpointer error i.e

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyRandomStringGeneratorClass obj = new MyRandomStringGeneratorClass();
       // String randomString = obj.generateRandomString();
        String secretFromRandomString = obj.generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString();
    }
}
```

I guess the best thing in this case I can do is to place a null check in the secret generator method for the field that if it is null , log a message in the console to the user that you have to generate a string a first to get the secret from that string, but it seems a bit of cliche to me.

i.e

```
public class MyRandomStringGeneratorClass
{
    private String generatedRandomString;
    public String generateRandomString()
    {
        //some logic
        this.generatedRandomString = someRandomStringGenerator();
    }
    public String generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString()
    {
      if(generatedRandomString==null)logSomeErrorAndReturn(); 
      //some encryption of the String 'generatedRandomString'
    }

}
```

The other thing i can think of is calling the method `generateRandomString()` from inside of the method `generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString()`. This will ensure that String was indeed generated and ecryption was performed on the same as well.

```
public class MyRandomStringGeneratorClass
{
    private String generatedRandomString;
    private String generateRandomString()
    {
        //some logic
        this.generatedRandomString = someRandomStringGenerator();
    }
    public String generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString()
    {
      generatedRandomString=generateRandomString(); 
    // encrypt the String now
    }

}
```

However I may not be able to return the plain generated random String(without declaring the field as public or unless I provide getter methods for the same).
Please suggest the appropriate way. Ask if further clarification needed.

Comment: You already know how to detect the situation. Up to you what to do when you find it. Throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to expose `generateRandomString` to the use anyway? I'd just make it an implementation detail, and encapsulate it inside `generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString`:

```
public String generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString() {
    if (generatedRandomString == null) {
        generatedRandomString = generateRandomString();
    }
    //some encryption of the String 'generatedRandomString'
    return encryptedString;
}
```

Comment: Nice point :) ,But I need to expose it because I am  saving the encrypted as well as plain data in my DB(consider that it is not a password , but just an encrypted string ). I think that next suggestion you are going to give is not to store the plain data whether it is password or something else. However , I was saving myself of repetitive encryption decryption process. But your suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Optional container object - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

```
public class MyRandomStringGeneratorClass 
{ 
    private Optional<String> generatedRandomString;
    public String generateRandomString()
    { 
        //some logic 
        this.generatedRandomString = Optional.of(someRandomStringGenerator());
        return generatedRandomString.get()
    } 
    public String generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString()
    { 
        if(generatedRandomString.isPresent())
        {
           //some encryption of the String 'generatedRandomString' 
        }
        else
        {
           // generatedRandomString is null and you can create new one and encrypt it
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the same as `generatedRandomString == null`? If you are using only one funcionality of a library, than can be easily reproduced like here, is it worth to include that lib?

Comment: Optional is for this use cases only.. Java 8 tells you avoid null checks and NPEs.. it is not at all expensive use this.

Answer (score 0):

Both(generateRandomString and generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString) the methods can be declared public to return the plain String and the encrypted String. Get a new Random string from generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString method, if the random string was not generated earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Null value in generateSecretFromGeneratedRandomString() method and if the value is null throw a custom exception, then handle the exception and ask user to generate a random string before generating secret. Safe and simple.

Answer (score 0):

How about an **immutable *RandomString*** class:

```
public class RandomString {

    private final String randomString;
    private final String secret;

    public RandomString() {
        this.randomString = someRandomStringGenerator();
        this.secret = computeSecret(this.randomString);
    }

    public String getString() {
        return randomString;
    }

    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }

}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final RandomString randomString = new RandomString();
        System.out.println(randomString.getString());
        System.out.println(randomString.getSecret());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you wish to enforce the sequence and still keep option of overriding both the micro methods open for overriding, Template method Design pattern can be used.

```
public class RndStringGenerator {
    private String randomString;
    public final String getSecretString() {
        generateRndString();
        return generateSecret();
    }
    public String getGeneratedRndString() {
        if (randomString == null) {
            generateRndString();
        }
        return randomString;
    }
    protected void generateRndString() {
        // some logic
        this.randomString = "Assume its Random String";
    }
    protected String generateSecret() {
        // some encryption
        return randomString;
    }
}
```

This is Template method which will allow to override protected methods but will lock the final method override to maintain the sequence.